# PyQt5 как корректно работать с дочерними окнами?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qmainwindow

После закрытия дочернего окна не получается заново открыть это же окно !
Какой лучше использовать корректный механизм для работы с окнами (закрытия окна и невозможность открытия дубликатов одного и того же окна) или таки работать с флагами ?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
flag = False


class Ui_test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("test")
        self.resize(380, 250)
        self.btntest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btntest.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 100, 40))
        self.btntest.setText('open other window')
        self.btntest.clicked.connect(open_otherwindow)

class OtherWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("otherwindow")
        self.resize(250, 250)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 100, 40))
        self.button.setText('hello')
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.nothing(1))

    def nothing(self, arg):
        pass

def open_otherwindow():
    global w, flag
    if not flag:
        w = OtherWindow()
        w.show()
    flag = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    test = Ui_test()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class OtherWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("otherwindow")
        self.resize(250, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('OtherWindow')
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                                 # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                                # + 
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) # +  
        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setFixedSize(100, 40)
        self.button.setText('hello')
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.nothing(1))
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)                  # + 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def nothing(self, arg):
        pass


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("test")
        self.resize(380, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                          # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                         # + 
        
        self.btntest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btntest.setMinimumHeight(40) 
        self.btntest.setText('Open other window')
        self.btntest.clicked.connect(self.open_otherwindow)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)           # +
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btntest, 
                alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
# !!! +++       
        self.otherWindow = OtherWindow()                                  # !!! +++

    def open_otherwindow(self):
        self.otherWindow.show()                                           # !!! +++
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    test = MainWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Thanks / дякую /  Danke shone / / рахмат / -->  вам S.Nick всемогущий )) в который раз

Comment: @almaz рад вам помочь.